# How to use get_context_data in django

Tags: python, django

I have 
**Views.py**

```
class newChartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "new_report_view.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(newChartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count'] = smslogger.objects.all()
        return context
```

and **new_report_view.html** as

```
{% for x in count %}
{{ x.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

and it show error

```
'module' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

**smsloggger**

```
model

class Log(models.Model):
   date= models.DateField()
   count=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "SMS Log"

   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.date,self.count
```

I want to have the data from smslogger app. How can I acheive it through TemplateView subclass

Comment: smslogger must a be model not app

Comment: Apps don't have data. Models do.

Comment: can you share smslogger model with us ? that will help to find out problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you let us know what smslogger.py contains ?

I think you might be need to do something like this.

```
from smslogger import YourModel

class newChartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "new_report_view.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(newChartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count'] = YourModel.objects.all()
        return context
```